# How to get rid of a "phantom" route that koa-router adds without being defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa, koa-router

I'm starting devel on very small app, and decided to use koa Framework with koa-router ( among some other middleware in the future)

Question is that after specifying my routes, a strange catch-all, no method, no url route appears

```js
// excerpt of /app/routes/admin

var router = require('koa-router')().prefix('/admin');

router.get('/a.html', function *(next){
  return this.render('a', {some: 'data'})
})

router.get('/index.html', function *(next){
  return this.render('index', {})
})

router.get('/b.html', function *(next){
  return this.render('b', {})
})

module.exports = router
```

```js
// excerpt of Main App
    
    // routes
    var adminRouter =  require('/app/routes/admin')
    this.app.use( adminRouter.routes())
    this.app.use( adminRouter.allowedMethods())
    
    // Checking Routes
    console.log(adminRouter.stack.map(i => i.path));
```

... which, when run, gives the following result:

```
    [ '(.*)',
  '/admin/a.html',
  '/admin/index.html',
  '/admin/b.html' ]
```

From where the hell is (.*) coming?

Also, if I enable the debugging for koa-router, I get

```
  koa-router defined route HEAD,GET /admin/list.html +46ms
  koa-router defined route HEAD,GET /admin/index.html +1ms
  koa-router defined route HEAD,GET /admin/queries.html +0ms
  koa-router defined route  (.*) +1ms
```

, so to make things even stranger, shows that this route has no associated method of any kind

Any idea of that "Phantom" entry?

Comment: I just tried out your code with a [minimal example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/26766ac4f6ba4125a5689e8e475f262d), and it seems to work fine so it must be coming from somewhere else that is not in the code you included. Could you share the rest of your code?

Comment: I just tried out you mini setup and it works for me too. Rest of code is like a 17 source files, but most of them have nothing to do with the http server, ON the rest of mmiddleware  it's pretty basic, and I even commented out to do the testing , so basically what you've seen its what there is.

Comment: Anyway getting deepre in question, it seems that the phantom route just appers in the very same moment of importing adminRouter Routes into main router. I ve test addming some  dummy routes on main router before that and Phantom route doesn't appear

Comment: Hmm, could you share more of your admin code? Right now, there isn't really a way to figure out what the issue is with just the code you currently have provided.

Comment: Ok, [here it is](https://gist.github.com/develmts/585ca1ed5c3c246cc4087e050d07a8da)

Comment: Dirty workaround follows

Comment: if (mainRouter.stack[0] == '(.*)')
        mainRouter.stack.shift()

Answer (score 0):

OK. Not exactly a solution, but at least it is not Phantom anymore
After digging  with the debugger, It seems that route aperas when a a middleware is added "globally" to the router, ie when your "use" it

```
router.use(anotherRouter.routes()
```

which makes perfect sense, as if you're adding a middleware "globally" that way, you expect that every request past through it

I opened the question because i was getting  404 not found For ALL my routes, and suspected this one was the offender, but in the end it was for a couple of different questions ( non reachable paths, non existent files, misconfiguration,etc)